# CRTP inside namespace vs typdefs and friends

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef, friend, crtp

I have battled all night with the compiler and I run out of ideas...

I have a CRTP construction inside a namespace that has a protected function.
The derived class (also inside that namespace) is typedefed to another name.

next to that I have a class (also typedefed to another name) with a static function that tries to call that function. So I start making friends but still the compiler (VS 2010 in my case) won't grand me access to the function.

as some code is probably more clear :

```
namespace foobar
{
namespace internal
{
    template <typename T>
    class A
    {
        friend class E;

    protected:
        void foo()
        {
            static_cast<T*>(this)->_foo();
        }
    };

    class B : public A<B>
    {
        friend class E;
        friend class A<B>;

    protected:
        void _foo()
        {
            printf("Foo from B\n");
        }
    };
}

typedef internal::B C;

class D
{
public:
    static void Bar();

};

typedef D E;

    void D::Bar()
    {
        C mB;
        mB.foo();
    }   
}//foobar namespace
```

can anybody tell me what i'm not seeing here and how this can be resolved ?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declarations `friend class E` forward-declare a `class foobar::internal::E` which has nothing to do with `class foobar::D`.  You have to declare `D` and `E` before declaring them as friends:

```
namespace foobar
{
  class D;
  typedef D E;

  namespace internal
  {
    template <typename T>
    class A
    {
      friend E;
      // ...
```

Note that this only works for C++11.  For C++03 you cannot declare a `typedef` as friend at all, there you need to write `friend class ::foobar::D`.